# How can I force the position of the divider, and place logo at a certain location?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, position, css-position

Here is what I have now :

[image]

I'm struggling trying to move my **divider** and my **book** up - maybe 10px.

I've tried to inspect them using dev tool and adjust the `padding`, and `margin`, but nothing seems to work.

I'm very curious and clueless right now.
I'm not sure why it stopping me at that orange dash line.
I need a little push here.

Can someone **please** tell me what I did wrong here?

Here is my live result: [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/e9L60rfr/21/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move everything below the perforated line, change the margin-top attribute of your `.tl-left` selector.

```
.tl-left{
    margin-top: -35px;
}
```

To move only the book image and vertical line do the following:

```
#mp-book{
    width: 76px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}

.vertical-line {
    border-left:3px solid silver;
    height:100px;
    text-align: center;
    width:2px;
    margin-left:48px;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Add `margin-top:-10px` to your `#mp-book` and `.vertical-line` selectors.

https://jsfiddle.net/e9L60rfr/23/

Comment: It doesn't work, sorry. ! Try it your self ! What did you see ?

Comment: It moves everything below the orange perforated line (in your image) towards the h2 element.

Comment: Did you read my description ? I only want to move my divider and my image logo, **Not** the whole thing.

Comment: Can you put your solution/suggestion in my Fiddle and update my Fiddle and include that fiddle link as part of your answer ?